# Why does "select count(*)" from nothing return 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-server-2012

With SQL Server 2012 :

```
use master
select *
```

yields

> Must specify table to select from

which is exactly what I would expect.

But the funny thing is that

```
use master
select count(*)
```

returns 1.

Can someone explain to me what is counted here?

Edit : And possibly include sources...

Comment: A count by definition has to return a value, so your query implicitly has one row in it - the result of the count.

Comment: @MarcB but why does it implicitly have one row and not 0.

Comment: because you're counting something. even if the count is zero, that zero has to be returned somehow, so a row is created to contain it. since that row is created, this vaporware table has one row in it, making the count 1.

Comment: If you had used `42` (or any other constant value) instead of `*` in the first case, you would not have gotten the error message,

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, their execution plans are pretty different. COUNT(42) is same as COUNT(*) but 42 yields a completely different source.

Comment: @MarcB I think you're right. This is a pretty useless discussion about SS internals (at least I can't find it anywhere) but I guess it's how you said

Comment: @Adriano: I wasn't referring to the `count()` case. I was referring to the **first** example and why `select *` generates an error and `select 42` doesn't. (And I don't care about the "execution plan" - this question is about the behaviour towards the user).

Comment: `select *` implies a column list, but this vaporware table (I like that!) doesn't actually have any columns, `select *` will fail. And, if you want to really make your head explode, it will work inside an exists clause (`where exists select *)`).

Comment: Well, where we need something like this?? why we really do something like `use master
select count(*)`

Comment: If anyone can give a reason why this behavior matters, I'll be impressed, comes up from time to time in discussion but never seen a situation where it matters.

Comment: @Goat : I never said that it really matters. I just hit F5 accidentally while this line was selected, and found this behavior both surprising and interesting.

Comment: @Johnny5 Makes sense, I wasn't being critical of the question, just legitimately interested to find out if there is a scenario where the behavior could have an impact.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQL Server is (behind the curtain) effectively applying a from to a dummy table, which has only one row.  Thus you will get 1 for your count.

```
select 'test'
```

will do the same thing, as an example, return 'test' one time.

It's like the DUAL table in Oracle, SYSDUMMY1 in DB2, etc.

As requested, here's a couple of links to MS Connect on this topic:

[Clicky](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/338532/count-returns-a-value-1)

[More Clicky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/671475/select-test-where-exists-select)

Comment: Exactly, same as if you do the following:

`SELECT COUNT(0)
SELECT COUNT(1)
SELECT COUNT('z')
SELECT COUNT(1254584)`

Comment: I'm not so sure. If you check **execution plans** for that queries you'll see they're pretty different (and SS understands this is a _select without query_ while the other one is a scan over a constant

Comment: I wasn't trying to explain exactly what SQL Server is doing with this, just why the query returns one row.  You are correct though, the explains are different.

Comment: @Adriano You are right. I checked the Query Plan just now, and the SELECT 42 (Select over constant) has no cost whereas COUNT(*) on nothing has a completely different EXEC Plan. Any idea why the difference? Just curious. I know this is a digression from OP's question, still... :)

Comment: @Andrew you can add this link in your answer: [Connect item: select 'test' where exists (select *)](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/671475/select-test-where-exists-select) The explanation by Microsoft confirms yours (thanks for the link should go to Michael Fredrickson.)

Comment: Here's another [connect item, where Microsoft states that this behavior is a bug (but the item is closed as won't fix)](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/338532/count-returns-a-value-1).

Comment: @Adriano That response from Microsoft looks inconsistent with the first one. How can we expect `SELECT 1, 'test', '2013-12-03'` to return one row but then `SELECT COUNT(*)` to raise error? Either both should be fixed or both allowed.

Comment: @ypercube if it wasn't a bug I would agree. In this case it may just be an implementation detail of COUNT(*). Whatever is the internal reason for that (I think we can't guess because we don't know how that stuff is implemented)...they filed that as bug (in the _who cares about this?_ section LOL)

Comment: @Adriano If you mean that it'a bug because it isn't ANSI/ISO standard compliant, I may agree. But looking from different angle, why is it a bug and not a feature?

Comment: The `select count(*)` is, I would say, a feature. It's no different than the `SYSDUMMY1` table in DB2, you just don't have to include the from clause.  Now, the `select *` not throwing an error in a where exists clause is a bug, and they are acknowledging that, just don't think it's worth fixing.